# <Design:Attribute> Documentation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, community-builder, design

I've been reading this documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder.htm) and so far it seems pretty straight forward on how to add input fields and pickers on the component pane when editing on the community builder.

However, I can't seem to find any documentation for possible creating check boxes, textarea and etc. Anyone know if this is possible or might be able to point me to documentations?

UPDATE:
adding screenshot to clarify what I'm talking about. I'm referring to the component pane or the property editor.

[image]

Comment: look under refrences--> component refernces , you will see all ui options that you can use on the component

Comment: @Rao hmmmm these are for ui though. I was talking more about <design:attributes />. Sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: kev_panda are you referring to LDS attributes, if so the documentation is here: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/activity-timeline/

Comment: @Rao No, I'm referring to the design resource interface for adding properties to a component on the community builder page. I'm going to update my question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At this point only attributes that are supported are String , boolean and int .

So this is how the design file will look

```
<design:component>
  <design:attribute name="SearchString" label="Search" description="Please add Search merge variable" />
  <design:attribute name="isValid" label="Valid" description="Checkbox" />
</design:component>
```

The design file will map to component attribute value .Note there is strict mapping with name of attribute matching to one is component

```
<aura:attribute name="SearchString" type="String" default="{!searchString}" access="global"/>
 <aura:attribute name="isValid" type="String" default="false" access="global"/>
```

You can also have a picker

```
<design:attribute name="Name" datasource="value1,value2,value3" default=”value1” />
```

Richtext is not possible currently .

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know. Hopefully, more support soon!

Comment: You can now build dynamic datasource :) : https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_picklists.htm