# Lightning component architecture suggestion needed

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I want to build something like this in the lightning component:

[image]

1. When "Main Heading" is checked then all option under it - "Sub Heading 1" and "Sub Heading 2" should be checked with their sub-options ("Sub Heading1 Child Option1", "Sub Heading2 Child Option 1" etc.) If they all are checked then unchecking any "sub heading" and "sub heading" child options should uncheck the "Main Heading" checkbox.
2. When "Sub Heading 1" is checked then it related sub-options should be checked. And same for "Sub Heading 2". Unchecking any of the child sub-options should uncheck the selected "Sub Heading".

So what would be the good architecture for this kind of requirement? The level of "Sub Heading" and "Sub Heading Child Option" is not fixed; they can be with any number of level in the hierarchy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursive methods and get help from a lightning tree component like this:

[Lightning Tree](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EOCHnUAP)

Comment: You could also have a look at (this answer)[http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163172/tree-structure-in-lightning] from @sfdcfox

Comment: Yes, thanks @John Thompson - I was looking for this but did not find it

Answer (score 0):

For main heading you should use design attributes in your component and use them as you  need. This question might help you getting started  with design attribute.

[<Design:Attribute> Documentation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128575/designattribute-documentation)

And for sub headings you should define your own logic to check child checkbook in JavaScript controller.

Comment: I think you miss the context of the question. I am looking for architect suggestions rather than user oriented options for which Design attributes are mainly used.