# Properties Menu for Custom Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, lightning-bolt, lightning-builder

In salesforce community builder how can I get the properties and attributes menu for custom lightning components as we have for standard lightning components as shown in the picture that I have for search?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use design attributes to achieve this

Please refer - [<Design:Attribute> Documentation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128575/designattribute-documentation)